# Pass data as a void* in C++

Tags: c++, curl, interface

I am using curl in my c++ program.  Curl can store 'user data' that is passed to it so that when I receive a curl HTTP call back I can then retrieve this user data again.

Curl will be storing this data as a void*.  I want to be able to pass data to a function like so:

```
void SomeFunction( const std::string& url, const std::string& username, const std::string& password, void* userData)
{
    //Pass userData to curl..blah blah
}
```

My question is what is the correct and proper C++ way to pass data as a void*??
Should I have an interface like so:

```
    class ICurlUserData
    {
    public:
        virtual void SetCurlData( void* pUserData ) = 0;
        virtual void* GetCurlData( void ) = 0;
    };
```

And then have a class implement this interface like so:

```
    class CurlUserData
    {
    public:
        CurlUserData() : m_userData(nullptr){};
        virtual ~CurlUserData(){};

        virtual void SetCurlData( void* pUserData ){ m_userData = pUserData;}
        virtual void* GetCurlData( void ){ return m_userData; }
    private:
        void* m_userData;
    };
```

And pass that like so:

```
void SomeFunction( const std::string& url, const std::string& username, const std::string& password, ICurlUserData* userData)
{
    CurlUserData data = static_cast<CurlUserData*>(userData);
    void* myData = data->GetCurlData();
    int myNumber = static_cast<int>(myData); 
    //blah blah
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Well, you have a bright answer in the question !  I guess another alternative could be to make a `template <type T> void SomeFunction( const string& url, const string& username, const string& password, T& userData)`

Comment: Why not just pass the userData as-is as a `void*` like you originally showed? Why go to elaborate lengths to coerce it? Let the caller pass whatever data it wants to `SomeFunction()`, it works just fine in C++. Just because C++ supports/emphasizes structured data doesn't mean you have to use it for everything. What if the caller wants to pass a simple `int*` pointer, for example? Wrapping it like you showed is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to pass `void*` data to a `curl` (or any other) C functions that calls you back is like this:

```
StronglyTyped myobj;

extern "C" void myfunc (void* arg)
{
   StronglyTyped* p_myobj = static_cast<StronglyTyped*>(arg);
   // do something
}


//.. somewhere in your code ...
curl_something(curlarg1, curlarg2, myfunc, static_cast<void*>(&myobj));
```

These three occurrences of `void*` should be the only ones you use.

**Update, following up to a discussion in comments**.

It is not possible to get rid of these `void*` occurrences. A C function cannot use templates, derived classes or all kinds of other advanced techniques. If it wants to call back a user function and pass some user data back to it, it must do with `void* pointers. So a C function that requires a callback typically accepts two parameters that look like that:

```
void c_function_with_a_callback ( ..., ..., 
                                void (*user_function)(void*), 
                                void* user_data);
```

The two actual parameters passed to the function must have *exactly* the types specified in the signature, so one **must** write a function that has this signature:

```
 void somefunction (void*);
```

and also **must** have a `void*` pointer to pass to it. The latter is typically obtained from a regular object pointer by casting. `somefunction` typically restores the strongly typed object pointer in the first line.

There is no need to have any other `void*` pointer — not any dictated by the "curl" function in question.

Indeed, should the offending function be written in C++, it could easily be a function template:

```
template <typename T>
void void cxx_function_with_a_callback (..., ...,
                                       void (*user_function)(T*),
                                       T* user_data);
```

No `void*` anywhere in this version, but it is fundamentally identical to the C version. The only differences between a system with a `c_function_with_a_callback` and a system with a `cxx_function_with_a_callback` are:

1. Type of `user_function`
2. Type of `user_data`
3. Presence or absence of two casts from and to `void*`

If a system with `cxx_function_with_a_callback` has no `void*` anywhere, an analogous system with `c_function_with_a_callback` should have `void*` pointers exactly in places enumerated above and nowhere else. If a system with `cxx_function_with_a_callback` requires `void*` for some reason or another, then a system with `c_function_with_a_callback` will also require `void*` in similar places, but these `void*` things have nothing to do with how `c_function_with_a_callback` stores user data.

Comment: Thanks for this.  But the function I'm passing my data to is a C++ function and not straight C.

Comment: `myfunc` is a C++ function. A C function would not be able to do a `static_cast`.

Comment: Yes but your C++ function is still using a void* as its parameter.  I'd like to get away from that if possible.

Comment: You can't. A curl function requires a `void(*)(void*)`, that is, a function that has a `void*` parameter. That's exactly what you should pass to it. Your attempt has about 6 occurrences of `void*`, none of which seem to serve any purpose. You should use `void*` in places where C or other legacy interface requires a `void*`. Your code doesn't attempt to call a legacy interface. Rather than solving global problems of how to pass `void*` in C++, which makes no sense, write down a signature of the`curl` function that you plan to call, and ask "how do I call this guy and get my data back?"